# Do I need to hurry in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

The nature of main quest-line in Cyberpunk 2077 compels you to finish it as soon as possible and ignore various side-quests.

However, when playing open world RPG, such approach will generally make you miss big parts of content.

Is there actually penalty in main-quest for taking too much time? Or is the pressure only story device without any *real* effect?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you generally don't need to hurry. Most quest states will wait for you until you return to play them. So you're free to do other things in the game and let those quests wait.

This also applies to side quests which you can accept, often via phone, by saying stuff like "yes I will come over to deal with it" (or similar), but you don't actually need to do that right away.

There is only one exception, though. It is the quest "Happy Together" where you need to talk to your neighbor (the one who doesn't want to speak with his police coworkers).

> The quest requests you to talk to Barry after he blocked to talk to his coworkers. You can't speak right away with him, but shouldn't wait to long either (skipping a few hours is enough). If you take to much time, then the quest can fail. You can read more about that quest here: https://www.thegamer.com/cyberpunk-2077-happy-together-save-barry/

Comment: May I ask, what you base your answer on? This is my impression from the game as well (I'm about 20 hours in) as well, but I would prefer something slightly more substantial.

Comment: @IvanLoginov I base it on my almost 100% playthrough experience.

Comment: You can even walk away from characters mid-conversation, do another questline, and return to continue the conversation. It's a bit immersion-breaking but on the other hand, it's convenient for the player.

Comment: I have the mission active (on my second playthrough) and have levelled up to level 30 so far and still have the mission. Is it disappearing based on a particular trigger?

Comment: @kalina I haven't tested it myself, so I can only rely on other sources. The linked page for example says the quest will "resolve on its own", so I guess you can't bring it to a good end, but the quest still exists in your log, you so can have the finalizing dialog with the other cops. I guess there they will tell you what has happened and the quest will then be done.

Comment: No worries I will let you know once I complete this playthrough, left that quest alone to see if it disappears

Comment: @kalina Thanks. Like I said, I don't think it will disappear automatically. You still need to talk to the coworkers, but certain outcomes are impossible for you due to waiting too long.

Comment: Yeah I already triggered the police bit as I left the building earlier in the game. Now I have completed nearly every available side quest (not been progressing the main story). I assume if anything is going to trigger its removal it will be main story so we'll know soon enough

Comment: There’s also a timer factor on some of Panam’s side quests (Riders on The Storm in particular, if I remember rightly)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Do you remember which part? Prior mission start or something in the mission itself?

Comment: As I recall, @Tom, you have 24 hours from when Panam calls to get to her and mount the rescue before the outcome changes.

Comment: There are tons of quests where you can't continue until a few hours after an event, or until a certain time of day _(Ex: after dropping off electro-penis guy; and first time you talk to Jackie)_ There's also [one report of the monk mission timing out](https://www.reddit.com/r/cyberpunkgame/comments/kf2nvv/be_advised_some_side_quest_are_timed_ingame_time/). It's weird to single the neighbor mission out.

Answer (score 4):

There are very few quests that have a hidden timer, neither of them is one of the main quests.

Examples that I know:

- [*Loosing my religion*](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/Sacrum_Profanum) will fail if you take too long time from taking the quest to saving the monk
- [*Violence*](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/Violence?so=search) might become unavailable for a week if you take too long before going to the Riot club
- [*Raymond Chandler Evening*](https://cyberpunk.fandom.com/wiki/Raymond_Chandler_Evening) might fail if you take too long to check on Pepe's wife.

In general, a rule of thumb can be like this: If the quest is either

- part of the main quest
- given by a fixer
- given by one of the important NPCs (Rogue, Panam, River etc)
- a part of a chain

then there is no need to hurry.